# smart contract that automatically forwards funds it receives

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

can have multiple addresses for users to send the ETH but store the ETH in one single wallet

Comment: I don't see the relevance between question title and description.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple smart contract with the `receive` function with `payable`. In this function you can add the logic to forward the incoming ETH to your desired wallet address.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#receive-ether-function